# Atuo click not working on appended anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On ajax response I have appended an `anchor` tag and then want to click this anchor tag automatically but this click event is not working on this appended `anchor` tag.
It is working for normal elements but not for appended content.
Here is this click event that I am trying

```
jQuery('#download_pdf_url').trigger('click');
```

Here how I am appending this anchor tag on ajax response first and then trying to trigger a click event.

```
var url_href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/pdf_files/file_" + data + ".pdf";
jQuery('.printable').append('<a id="download_pdf_url" style="display:none;" href="" target="_blank" download>Download</a>');
jQuery('#download_pdf_url').attr('href', url_href);
jQuery('a#download_pdf_url[href$=".pdf"]').attr('download', '').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Actually I want to download a pdf on ajax response and I have tried different function but these functions are not supported in all browsers. For example I have used this but it is not working in chrome

```
window.open(url_href, '_blank');
```

So I am trying to find out a solution that will work in all browsers. I have already added `download` and `target` attribute to my anchor tag and want this click event to trigger automatically. Any suggestion about this will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you add the anchor tag? Could you please add that code?

Comment: @PrerakSola I have added that code as well.

Comment: Try raising the event through native JS instead: `jQuery('#download_pdf_url')[0].click()` or `document.getElementById('download_pdf_url').click()` although note that this may still not work as the event was not raised from user interaction

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan
document.getElementById('download_pdf_url').click(); is working for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are attempting to automatically trigger the `a` element to start the download, then you will need to raise a native click event on it, ie. not through jQuery. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('download_pdf_url').click()
```